Is there a standard set of characters which are generated by password generators, for example by web browsers such as Chrome?
Do randomized password generators usually have a standardized set of characters which they can produce as output?
I am trying to implement some logic for password validation.
It would be frustrating for a user if the logic which is implemented to validate the password does not match that of the logic of password generators in general. (In the title I used the example of the Google Chrome / Chromium Browser password generation feature, but this question doesn't have to give answers specific to Chrome.)
It would seem obvious that characters A-Z, a-z, 0-9 should be included as permissable characters in any validation logic.
Some special symbols should obviously be included, such as !, @, #, $, %, ^, &, *, ,, .,, -, +, _, =, ?.
Others I am not sure about. I don't recall ever seeing a password generated with either a back-quote, a single-quote or a double-quote character.
Similarly, parenthesys (), brackets [] and braces {}?
I am fairly sure greater than/less than (angle brackets) <> are commonly used by password generation logic.
Remaining special symbols on US keyboards include ~\|/.
The password validation function I am designing is relatively simple.

It checks the length to ensure the password is a minimum of 10 characters
It checks that only permissable characters are included
It doesn't require a minimum count of upper case/lower case/numeric or special characters (some strong passwords, such as a sequence of 4 random words, don't require these)

The problem I face is I don't know which special characters should be considered as permissable vs not permitted.
It might be confusing to include types of quotes for example, because a password like "apple" becomes ambiguous to a human reader. (Are the quotes included?)

Are you at liberty to say more about what the use case is? Normally, human-generated password composition is enforced at the point of initial data entry level only, and for the rest of the (randomly generated) passwords, there's no need to "validate" that a password is specifically a valid Google password.

@RoyceWilliams Yes sure - this logic is built into the backend of some system which processes signup requests. It checks for "sensible" passwords. That includes a minimum length and no whitespace characters. However there might be other sensible rules which should be applied. For example, no quotes. I don't want to enforce any of these rules if password generators would typically produce those characters in their output. ...

... For example, Google Chrome has a password generator built into it. When a user signs up to this website, the backend should not prevent them from using a password that Chrome might generate.

Ah, gotcha. OK, I've answered in that context.

The non-answer that's actually the best answer:
If it's a printable character (in ASCII, UTF-8, or your target encoding) you should allow it.
This is because restricting characters allowed in password composition reduces security.
Password diversity -- specifically:

density (supporting as many characters as possible, achieving  diversity necessary to pack the most randomness into the smallest space),
length (the diversity necessary to support the equivalent randomness for longer strings based on smaller character sets, like a long passphrase consisting only of lower-case characters and spaces), and
unpredictability (the diversity necessary to allow "weird" passwords that might be harder for non-expert passwords to crack offline)

... is a feature.
By contrast, it's a security "smell" (concurrent indicator of poor security practices) to have a lack of support for password diversity. Forbidding characters because they "might have security problems" such as SQL escapes, etc. (because the only truly secure way to manage this is with parameterized SQL, which is explicitly designed to accept all printable characters without trying to interpret them as SQL syntax).
In fact, even NIST 800-63b says:

Verifiers SHOULD NOT impose other composition rules (e.g., requiring
mixtures of different character types or prohibiting consecutively
repeated characters) for memorized secrets.

If your solution is robustly able to allow all printable characters at significant lengths, then your solution is maximizing security.
(Don't get me wrong - I'd be super interested in the answers to your question. But those answers should not be used to restrict password composition!)

Agreed, with the caveat that Unicode may cause problems, for example with varying compositions on different platforms, or some platforms not allowing input of non-ASCII characters in password fields; so you may want to restrict the character set to printable ASCII to save on support costs.

I agree with what you are saying in principle, but I'm not sure that applies to languages outside of English where characters cannot be represented by ASCII. It would be good to get some further thoughts on this.

Should you allow a tab in a password field for example? What happens if on some platforms, tab is captured as an input field changing character?

What about a new line? CR or LF?

Good question. Neither tab nor newline are considered "printable characters" in this context. They are sometimes found in naive password corpora, but they are not considered valid for "natural" (human-entered) passwords, in part because of the history of password entry in various interface (enter would submit the password, tab would move to the next field in a web form, etc).
